# Multiple image Background <div> repeat

Tags: css, ipad, mobile-safari, tumblr

I'm trying to finish a work around the iPad PNG / background image pixel size limit for a tumblr site.  The content area of the site uses an unlimited scroll function, and has a huge vertical background that reveals more characters as you scroll down.

I've broken the background image up into multiple pngs, and set the position and everything is looking great.. the last thing I can't figure out, however, is how to make the whole cluster repeat.  If I set background-repeat: repeat-Y; the images all pile up on top of each other.

Thanks, Code blow:

Drats

```
#contnetAreaBack {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-image:url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_01.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_02.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_03.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_04.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_05.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_06.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_07.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_08.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_09.png'), url('http://www.dratsum.com/clientDev/cartoonNetwork/2012-09-11-SuperJail-Tumblr/images/ContentBg_10.png');
        background-position:center 0px, center 1000px, center 2000px, center 3000px, center 4000px, center 5000px, center 6000px, center 7000px, center 8000px, center 9000px;
        background-size: auto auto;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment:scroll;
        width:100%;
        padding-bottom:500px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your images that you use the same yellow pipe with varying characters an cracks. Maybe you could make the background be the first line of pixels for the yellow pipe, and make that repeat on y. Then you could run a php script that injects smaller png files with just the characters/ cracks as floating images over the pipe based on a while loop that ends when you run out of characters. I'm not familiar with the limitations you mention, but if you don't have a limit on the number of images you can use that method should work, unless you want to scroll infinitely as the page gets longer, looping back through characters. In that case, I would try the same solution, but instead of using the number of characters as my php loop constraint I would try take the height of the page before injecting the overlay images, divide it by the height of one overlay image (I imagine all of your bg images have the same height) and round up. This is a spitball solution, if you see any big issues I can be more specific for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a %(mod) in javascript to repeat the image once the mod equals a certain value.

Basically, you'll need to put all those broken down images into a single div,put a duplicate div beneath it and then repeat on mod.